# max-width using em

Tags: css, font-size

Can someone please explain how the em unit of measurement works with the max-width css property?   On my screen resolution of 1920 x 1080 I have found that setting the max-width to 140em is the equivalent of max-width of 100%.

Comment: Are you sure that it's *actually* the width of your monitor, or is it just clipping because you're setting the maximum width, and not the actual width?

Comment: You probably need to understand the em unit itself first.

Comment: the amazing em unit - http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/css2em.htm

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Em is just another unit. It depends on the font size. Current font size (e.g. 14px) = 1em. 2em doubles the font size (28px).

Have a look at your screen resolution: 1920/140 = 13,714285714 - looks like your current font size is 14px. Therefore setting `max-width:140em` is the same like `max-width:1920px` or `max-width:100%` - in your special case.